# Laravel 4: passing parameters inside route without closures

Tags: php, laravel-4, url-routing

I have a controller which I want to use for many routes. I need to pass some parameters, but I don't know how to do that without using closures.

I have an action like this:

```
public function show($view, $param)
{
    return View::make($view)->with('param', $param);
}
```

Now I know I can generate a route like this:

```
Route::get('/myfirstlink', array('uses' => 'MyController@show') );
```

but I want to pass $view and $param without passing them in the url.
Something like:

```
Route::get('/myfirstlink', array('uses' => 'MyController@show') ); //with $view='firsttemplate',$param='firstparam'
Route::get('/mysecondlink', array('uses' => 'MyController@show') ); //with $view='secondtemplate',$param='secondparam'
```

How to do that in the cleanest way?

Thank you in advance

**Edit for clarification:**

I don't need the user to specify values. I want to call the same controller action with different parameters... something like this:

```
Route::get('/myfirstlink', array('uses' => 'MyController@show', 'atts' => array('view'=>'firsttemplate','param'=>'firstparam')) );
```

Comment: Where would your $view and $param be coming from? Form inputs?

Comment: I want to hardcode it inside my route.
Something like

    Route::get('/myfirstlink', array('uses' => 'MyController@show', 'atts' => array('view'=>'firsttemplate','param'=>'firstparam')) );

Comment: You could do a `switch(Request::path())` inside your `show()` method, `Request::path()` would give you either "myfirstlink" or "mysecondlink" but that would not be clean like you wanted. I still don't see why you cannot have them as separate routes though. If you could provide a real-world scenario then I might be able to help more.

Comment: The point is not to manage routes inside the controller. I already asked in the laravel irc channel, but they didn't get the point.
It seems that the simplest (but horrible) method is:
`Route::get('/myurl1', function(){ return (new MyController)->show('myfirstparam','mysecondparam'); });`
If you have suggestions to improve it it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an session, or send via input hidden, or a cookie.
But in your case i recommend use sessions, you can destroy/change/create it anytime.

Comment: I don't need to send it, nor storing in session. I simply need to pass some parameters to the controller action directly.